# Open multiple links keep signed in all the time

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have the following code that enables me to sign in specific url then to open multiple links related to that website

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long

Set bot = New ChromeDriver
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))

With bot
    .Start "chrome", "url"
    .Get "/"

    .FindElementById("login-trigger").Click
    .FindElementById("username").SendKeys "username"
    .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "password"
    .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='actions']/input").Click
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

    Stop
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If Not IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then
            .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", arr(i)
            .SwitchToNextWindow
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

The code works fine and I can sign in the website (It is by default the check box of "Remember me" is on ) .. But as for the links that opened at the loop doesn't refer to the website signed in ..

How can I keep the sign in in all tabs that will be opened through the loop?

Comment: I've not worked with Selenium before, but from a tool-agnostic perspective, being asked to sign in inside the loop means the code inside the loop is running in its own "context" or "session"? Generally when you successfully sign in, the server's response contains certain information (maybe cookie(s) which the server associates with an "authorised" session/client). It's up to the client to persist/include that information in subsequent requests (to continue to access privileged resources). Seems like the code in the loop is not aware of the existing session, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All the code is executed in the same session.. So I think this is weird as I have experimented with another website and the code works fine for the other